# Why does the MouseMove event not work if mouse loses focus on object?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mouse

I basically have a simple problem in my program that I just want to make sure goes right. It should on the click of the mouse button add the `MouseEventHandler` and then move the circle along with the mouse until the event handler gets removed. I simplified the code to the very basics:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="grid1" Background="White" MouseLeftButtonUp="grid_MouseUp">
        <Ellipse Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Fill="Black" MouseLeftButtonDown="ellipse1_MouseDown" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static Point _oldPoint = new Point(), _newPoint = new Point();

    private void ellipse1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _oldPoint = e.GetPosition(grid1);
        grid1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(grid_MouseMove);
    }

    private void grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(grid_MouseMove);
    }

    private void grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _newPoint = e.GetPosition(grid1);
        ellipse1.Margin = new Thickness(ellipse1.Margin.Left - _oldPoint.X + _newPoint.X, ellipse1.Margin.Top - _oldPoint.Y + _newPoint.Y, 0, 0);
        _oldPoint = _newPoint;
    }
}
```

Now in general this code works fine and I think is quite neat as it doesn't check the movement of the mouse until one actually presses the button. However, my question is as follows:

I had to add the `MouseMove` event to the grid rather than to the circle, because once the mouse pointer loses focus of the circle (by moving the mouse too fast) it doesn't trigger the MouseMove event anymore. But why exactly does that happen? At the beginning of the event the mouse was definitely above the circle and then it moved. Yes, it moved away from the circle but shouldn't that still trigger the event?

Comment: Have you tried [Mouse.Capture Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591452.aspx)?

Comment: @LPL How do I use the Mouse.Capture method? I looked at the msdn article but the direct use was not very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [capture the mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591452.aspx) and handle all events in your ellipse.

```
<Grid Name="grid1" Background="White">
    <Ellipse Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="ellipse1" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Fill="Black"
             MouseLeftButtonDown="ellipse1_MouseDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="ellipse1_MouseUp" />
</Grid>
```

with this code behind

```
private void ellipse1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(ellipse1);
    _oldPoint = e.GetPosition(grid1);
    ellipse1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(ellipse1_MouseMove);
}

private void ellipse1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(null);
    ellipse1.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(ellipse1_MouseMove);
}
```

I've moved and renamed grid_MouseMove to ellipse1_MouseMove.

Comment: Thanks, great use for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what Peter said, if you use the `Grid.MouseDown` event and checked if the  `oldPoint` is within `Ellipse` and have then handled the `MouseMove` event, this odd behavior wont be seen.

I also suggest exploring `drag` events.

Comment: How exactly could I use drag events in this context? I know of dragging information, but can I also use it to drag a WPF item?

Comment: About your first suggestion, you mean trigger the same function (MouseMove) in addition via `MouseLeave`?

Comment: @Phil, drag drop events works on any WPF item, even the `Adorner` Layer.

Answer (score 1):

A control only gets the mouse-events as long as the mouse is hovering over that particularly control.

If moving to a new control, the mouse is getting unhooked from the old control and hooked to the new control.

There are ways where you can create a global hook attached to the entire process, but I guess this is not what we are talking about.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I thought it might be something like that. So the event is triggered once the mouse gets its new position and not when it changes its initial position?

Comment: Its a little bit more complexed than that. There are several events involved - also some who still inform the old control about a button release.

Comment: Aren't OnMouseEnter/Leave triggered "OnEnter/Leave"? How would the circle move along with my mouse if the mouse is in the beginning always moved within the circle and therefore has neither entered nor left the circle?

Comment: If you want your mouse to be hooked to the circle at all times, you should definitely use SetWindowsHookEx/UnhookWindowsHookEx.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but it seems a bit too much effort to something as simple as that...

Comment: Well, its not that difficult to do and it opens up new opportunities - try start here http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=SetWindowsHookEx&namespace=[All].

Comment: I will look that up thank you. I marked the other answer as accepted, since it solved directly my problem, but I make sure to see how the hooks work.